# Can I preview a image of my Amazon s3 without downloading it completely?

Tags: image, amazon-s3, download

I am mounting a gallery with photos stored in a amazon s3 server.

To purposes of speed, I don't want to load completely all of them once the client open the gallery.

There is any way to download only a miniature of the image or something like that?

(I'm working with php/symfony2/wordpress just for detail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can add compression to your flow:

1. You cancompress server side before the picture is passed to the client.

   **Pro** - Doesn't need extra storage

   **Con**- Uses computing
2. You can compress once the picture is uploaded and store a thumbnail version and the high quality version.

   **Pro** - Does not use computing every single time someone requests a picture

   **Con** - would use slightly more storage

Comment: I took the first option, I don't expect to have a big flow so I am downloading the images, making a miniature and passing for the client them with the link to the original in Amazon.