# S3 view Files in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to **view files** Such as excel or zip or any other files in the **browser** without getting downloaded.
I am able to display image and **pdf** files in the browser but unable to view any other format's such as **zip** or **xls**.
I am storing my files in **S3**.

What should i do?

Comment: Zip, xls files cannot be viewed on the browser they are ment to download.

Comment: check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40791061/can-i-preview-a-image-of-my-amazon-s3-without-downloading-it-completely)

Comment: Google Drive has a similar functionality @PraveenGovind

Comment: Google drive and s3 are completely different, Google converts every file to webview.

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers are not able to natively display most file types. They can render **HTML** and can display certain types of **images** (eg JPG, PNG), but only after these files are actually downloaded to your computer.

The same goes for **PDFs** -- they are downloaded, then a browser plug-in renders the content.

When viewing file (eg Excel spreadsheets and PDF files) within services like Gmail and Google Drive, the files are typically **converted into images on the server-end** and those images are sent to your computer. Amazon S3 is purely a storage service and does not offer a conversion service like this.

**Zip files** are a method of compressing files and also storing multiple files within a single archive file. Some web services might offer the ability to list files within a Zip, but again Amazon S3 is purely a storage service and does not offer this capability.

To answer your *"What should I do?"* question, some options are:

- **Download** the files to your computer to view them, or
- Use a storage service that offers these capabilities (many of which store the actual files in Amazon S3, but add additional services to convert the files for viewing online)

Comment: Can you name some? Or does s3 offer any additional plugin to do so? @John

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit too late but did you try [Filestash](https://www.filestash.app/aws-s3-explorer.html)? *(I made it)*

That's what it looks like when you open a xls document on S3:

[image]

I aim to support all the common formats and the already supported list is rather big already